# AWK: how to have backreference \1 in gensub() function's regex field?

Tags: regex, awk, backreference

I have the following pattern:

```
$ echo -e "1>1>659,659>659>660\n1>1>683,683>683>684\n1>1>712,712>712>713\n1>1>1080648,1>1>1080660\n1>1>1081100,1>1>1081114"
1>1>659,659>659>660
1>1>683,683>683>684
1>1>712,712>712>713
1>1>1080648,1>1>1080660
1>1>1081100,1>1>1081114
```

I want to replace patterns where the same numbers appear sequentially between commas and the larger than (>) sign. So, to identify with grep I would do:

```
$ echo -e "1>1>659,659>659>660\n1>1>683,683>683>684\n1>1>712,712>712>713\n1>1>1080648,1>1>1080660\n1>1>1081100,1>1>1081114" |
grep -Eo "([0-9]+),\1>\1"

659,659>659
683,683>683
712,712>712
```

That is two back-references to the same group.

I know that using gensub() in awk I can have back-references in the replacement field. But how could I have that in the regexp field? Something like this:

```
result = gensub(/([0-9]+),\\1>\\1/,"my replaced string", "g", string)
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Assuming what you're doing is legal then it seems like it should be just `\1` not `\\1`

Comment: Wouldn't sed be a better candidate for this?

Comment: Can you give us an example of the output you are expecting?

Comment: I am not quite sure whether you do accept `perl` but you could have `echo your_string | perl -pe "s/([0-9]+),\1>\1//"`

Comment: I need this awk command to be part of a bigger program in awk, but Ed Morton's answer below did it (without gensub)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Awk does not support backreferences in a regexp because to do so would require a much slower regexp engine than awk uses (see [https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html](https://swtch.com/%7Ersc/regexp/regexp1.html)) and it's not necessary and rarely desired. This may be what you're trying to do, using GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match():

```
$ awk 'match($0,/([0-9]+),/,a){ sub(a[1]","a[1]">"a[1],"my replaced string") } 1' file
1>1>my replaced string>660
1>1>my replaced string>684
1>1>my replaced string>713
1>1>1080648,1>1>1080660
1>1>1081100,1>1>1081114
```

or with any awk:

```
$ awk 'match($0,/([0-9]+),/){ a=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH-1); sub(a","a">"a,"my replaced string") } 1' file
1>1>my replaced string>660
1>1>my replaced string>684
1>1>my replaced string>713
1>1>1080648,1>1>1080660
1>1>1081100,1>1>1081114
```

Comment: that is perfect. I was so focused on gensub() that I totally forgot about match(). I was about to say that your gawk approach works with awk as well but I had not realized that when you have gawk installed "awk" is just a symlink to gawk. But it works, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `sed` solution that does the trick.

```
sed 's|\([0-9]\+\),\1>\1|Replaced string|g'

echo -e "1>1>659,659>659>660\n1>1>683,683>683>684\n1>1>712,712>712>713\n1>1>1080648,1>1>1080660\n1>1>1081100,1>1>1081114" | sed 's|\([0-9]\+\),\1>\1|Replaced string|g'
1>1>Replaced string>660
1>1>Replaced string>684
1>1>Replaced string>713
1>1>1080648,1>1>1080660
1>1>1081100,1>1>1081114
```

Hope you can live with `sed` instead of `awk`

But if `awk` is mandatory here is an awkward `awk` script for this.

```
awk -F "[>,]" '{sub($3","$3">"$3,"Replaced string")}1'

echo -e "1>1>659,659>659>660\n1>1>683,683>683>684\n1>1>712,712>712>713\n1>1>1080648,1>1>1080660\n1>1>1081100,1>1>1081114" | awk -F "[>,]" '{sub($3","$3">"$3,"Replaced string")}1'
1>1>Replaced string>660
1>1>Replaced string>684
1>1>Replaced string>713
1>1>1080648,1>1>1080660
1>1>1081100,1>1>1081114
```

If you want to validate that 3rd field is always numeric.
Add the following condition:

```
awk -F "[>,]" '$3 ~ "^[0-9]+$"{sub($3","$3">"$3,"Replaced string")}1'
```

Comment: Good to know that backreferences work with sed, but I need it in awk. Ed Morton answer did it.... but I gave an upvote because this is probably useful.